# find a name in a sqlite table and return the id?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, select, jdbc

What I'm trying to do seems simple but I get this error    `SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: user1)`

```
public String getIdUser(String name) {
        try {
            this.stat = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT id_user FROM User WHERE name = " + name;
            ResultSet user = stat.executeQuery(sql);
            return user.toString();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return  null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or SQLite? You are mentioning both in the tags. Also you are creating the query dynamically, and have just experienced an SQL injection attack from yourself. :)

Comment: first what you want to select it seems your query not return any thing, second the string should be between two quotes `name = '" + name + "'";` but I strongly not advice this way, third use PrepapredStatement instead forth what you expect to get from `user.toString()` Instead I think you mean `if(user.next()){ return user.getString("colomnName")}`

Comment: this two things fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
String sql = "SELECT  FROM User WHERE name = " + name;
```

with

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE name = " + name; // you can also specify a column/columns instead of *
```

Comment: given the title of the question and the method name is called `getIdUser` one would think maybe OP is after `String sql = "SELECT ID FROM User WHERE name = " + name;`?. Nevertheless retrieving a user Id by the user name is unusual, unless user name is unique ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

Without quoting the `name` string it's interpreted as column name, and thus the error you see. You could surround it with single quotes, but that's still generally a bad practice, and will leave the code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Additionally, you're missing the select list (specifically, the `id_user` column), and missing getting it from the result set.
And finally, you forgot to close the statement and the result set.

If you put all of these corrections together, you should use something like this:

```
public String getIdUser(String name) {
    try (PreparedStatmet ps = 
         conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id_user FROM User WHERE name = ?")) {

        ps.setString(1, name);
        try (ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery()) {
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getString(1);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @YCF_L I don't understand this comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @YCF_L arg - I addressed this in the text of my answer, but neglected to fix it in the code I provided. Good catch, thanks! Edited and fixed.

Comment: this one doesn´t work for me, I get error here stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ?")

Comment: @majovlas care to share the error, or am I supposed to guess?

Comment: @majovlas I fixed the column to `id_user` as you've edited that in your question - try with that.

Comment: @majovlas `stat` should be `PreparedStatement stat` not `Statement stat` +1 Mureinik

Comment: @YCF_L good point - edited my answer to make it more obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I see many problems in your code :

## First

Your query should return something it should be :

```
SELECT col_name1, col_name2, ... FROM User ...
```

Or if you want to select every thing :

```
SELECT * FROM User ...
```

## Second

String or Varchar should be between two quotes, your query for example should look like :

```
SELECT col_name1 FROM User WHERE name = 'name'
```

## Third

I don't advice to use concatenation of query instead use Prepared Statement it is more secure and more helpful (I will provide an example)

## Forth

To get a result you have to move the cursor you have to call `result.next()`

## Fifth

Name of variable should be significant for example  `ResultSet` should be `ResultSet rs` not `ResultSet user`

Your final code can be :

```
PrepareStatement prst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT colName FROM User WHERE name = ?");
prst.setString(1, name);
ResultSet rs = prst.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
   reuturn rs.getString("colName");
}
```